# How to get the sent emails through Outlook using exchange powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server

I would like to know how can I pull all the sent emails from Exchange.
The problem is that when i use it i get multiple items for one email
For example:

sent time                  sender           recipient
1/1/2016 08:12:33          aaa@aa.com       dd@ddd.com
1/1/2016 08:12:33          aaa@aa.com       bb@bb.com

So I tried to use distinct (sent time) to get all the emails,
And i get another problem:
The problems happens when the sever of the recipient
Is in somewhere else in the world.

For example

sent time                  sender           recipient
1/1/2016 08:12:33          aaa@aa.com       dd@ddd.com
1/1/2016 08:12:34          aaa@aa.com       bb@bb.com

And I know for sure it's the same email because it's not make sense that some one sent two emails in difference of one seconds.
So i tried to add the file size and it didn't helep me either.
So my question is:
Do I have a column that represent uniqe key for an email that was sent
Like:                       Sender           Recipient     Key

```
1/1/2016 08:12:33          aaa@aa.com       dd@ddd.com     5126
1/1/2016 08:12:34          aaa@aa.com       bb@bb.com      5126
1/1/2016 08:13:54          aaa@aa.com       zz@zz.com      5127
```

I'm not an IT guy so I need a scrypt that will solve this issue in Powershell
(I'll deliver this scrypt to my IT guy)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is not clear your referring to using a Method but provide no example code. Please edit your question and include the cmd or code you are using.

Comment: I'm not the one who using the scriprt,

Comment: I'm not the one who using the scriprt, and my question is mianly on what's the name of the column

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is one more row (Eventid), which states clearly, what happened.
In example, when a message is received, there is a RECEIVE Event and a STOREDRV Event.

Comment: It's not gives me the solution I want because when I download the data in CSV I get                                                                                                                                                                                              1/1/2016 08:12:33 To aaa@aa.com dd@ddd.com 5126                                 1/1/2016 08:12:34 CC aaa@aa.com bb@bb.com 5126                                          And actually I sent only one email                                                                           with one agent as To, and the second as CC

Comment: Check [link](http://exchangeserverpro.com/exchange-server-faq-message-tracking-include-bcc-recipients) . This should give you To, CC, BCC in recipientstatus field.